# Why don't Libre Office command line options seem to work on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, libreoffice-writer

This is LO 6.0.7.3 on Windows 7 Enterprise.  All other instances of LO have been shut down (I discovered in Linux that this was vital.)

Here is example non-output:

```
C:\Users\[snip]>"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe" --cat "Some file.docx"

C:\Users\[snip]>
C:\Users\[snip]>"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe" --version

C:\Users\[snip]>
```

It's in the --help output, so you'd think it should work.

```
   --cat           Dump text content of the following files to console
                   (implies --headless). Cannot be used with --convert-to.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those options are not shown on the Libre Office Help page which discusses [command line options and Windows](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters).

As to why they are not available, *the place to ask would be the* [Libre Office Forum](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/scope:all/sort:age-desc/tags:common,command-line/page:1/).

Comment: I edited the answer showing that `--cat` is mentioned in the `--help` output.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered about `--cat`, too.

It's probably some old dead code in LibreOffice, or a bug, and The Right Thing To Do™ is [report it](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport) in the issue tracker. (I didn't look, but I'll bet there's already an open issue.)

However,

```
path\to\soffice --writer --convert-to txt filename.ext
```

will probably do what you expected `--cat` to do.